# SQL Server use variable to define decimal places

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have this question: I have a column called `Quantity` that is declared as `DECIMAL(10, 2)` and if I do this query:

```
SELECT Quantity 
FROM myTable
```

I obtain a value like this: `123.00`

I have another table where I store my configuration things and one of these is the decimal places, where I wish use to cast the column.

But this query doesn't work:

```
DECLARE @DECIMAL_PLACES INTEGER

SELECT @DECIMAL_PLACES = CAST(sConfigValue AS INT) 
FROM dtConfig 
WHERE sConfig = 'DecimalPlaces'

-- @DECIMAL_PLACES have a value of 1 for example:
SELECT 
    CONVERT(DECIMAL(10, @DECIMAL_PLACES), Quantity) AS QuantityFormatted
FROM 
    myTable
```

I get an error

> `@DECIMAL_PLACES` is not an *INTEGER*

Is it possible do this?

Thanks

Comment: Pretty sure this can't be don't without using dynamic sql to inject the value into the statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could you use dynamic SQL?

```
DECLARE @DECIMAL_PLACES INTEGER
SELECT @DECIMAL_PLACES = CAST(sConfigValue AS INT) FROM dtConfig 
WHERE sConfig = 'DecimalPlaces'
-- @DECIMAL_PLACES have a value of 1 for example:
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @SQL = N'SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL(10, ' + CAST(@DECIMAL_PLACES AS NVARCHAR(20)) + N'), Quantity) AS QuantityFormatted FROM myTable'
EXEC (@SQL)
```

However, it's better to do formatting in the client.

Answer (score 5):

I've found a tricky solution, to avoid to use dynamic SQL:

```
DECLARE @DECIMAL_PLACES INTEGER

SELECT @DECIMAL_PLACES = CAST(sConfigValue AS INT) 
FROM dtConfig 
WHERE sConfig = 'DecimalPlaces'

-- @DECIMAL_PLACES have a value of 1 for example:
SELECT 
    LTRIM(STR(ROUND(Quantity, @DECIMAL_PLACES), 10, @DECIMAL_PLACES)) AS QuantityFormatted
FROM 
    myTable
```

hope this will be useful for everyone :)

thanks

Comment: You can even cast that value as *float* if you do not want the value as a string.

Comment: From my experience this is slightly different to decimal(x,y) in the way it rounds the number. decimal(3,1) will round 3.05 as 3.1 and your method will round 3.05 as 3.0 if @decimalplaces = 1. So if you care about rounding .5 up, your method needs some further adjusting. It will round 3.06 as 3.1 though.

Comment: @Tomislav3008 is correct, as-is it will not round one decimal place correctly. If the type [quantity] is not specified (or defined as a float) it will treat it as a float and not round it correctly. Slightly modifying OP's answer to LTRIM(STR(ROUND(CAST(Quantity AS DECIMAL(x,y)), @DECIMAL_PLACES), 10, @DECIMAL_PLACES)) should address that issue.